# My dog won’t stay in doggy-bed

Tags: dogs, puppy

How do I get my puppy to stay in his doggy-bed while playing with his toys?  He’ll stay in it and play with the toys momentarily and then he’ll chuck one outside of the bed with his mouth and then proceeds to play with it on the couch.  It doesn’t matter which item- it can be a bully-stick or a chew toy- no matter what, he invariably ends up outside of the doggy-bed and on to the couch.  I’d like to keep him in his bed to prevent tearing up my leather couch.  Thanks!

Comment: Can you please explain why you want him to stay in his bed while playing or what you're trying to accomplish by keeping him in his bed? How is his leaving his bed a problem?

Comment: A very important question: how old / young is your dog? I have a feeling that we deal with a puppy here :)

Comment: I just clarified my question.  And yes, @virolino, indeed, he’s a puppy. :D

Comment: A simple and temporary solution is to put a cheap blanket or old bedcloth over the seat of the couch. We have a similar arrangement to protect the fabric of our sofa against dirty paws. Depending on the size of the couch you can cut one blanket in half to cover more area with no extra cost. Push the edges of the blanket into the crevices to keep it in place.

Comment: @Elmy, I caved and already did that after posting the question yesterday; I figured that would be a good temporary solution until we can figure out how to get him to stay in his doggy-bed while playing with his toys.  However, he did start barking at me after I put the blanket down- so maybe he likes the feel of the leather too!  Thanks for the recommendation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most simple thing to understand is that the puppy is young and independent. Sometimes rebellious :) Just like human babies, and like any other babies.

One reason why the dogs (regardless of age) prefer to go to the bed / sofa, even when it is forbidden, is that they need to be as close as possible with their masters, even when their masters are not available for them. And the beds and the sofas are the most impregnated things in the house with the scent of the owner. In a twisted way, they actually show affection by going there - they are happy when they feel their master's scent.

Another thing is that sometimes dogs (or children) feel lonely, and they would try anything to draw their master's attention - usually by doing what is forbidden. That is even more visible with cats ;)

I can think of few ways to fix the problem.

- Continue to lovingly train the dog to not go to the bed / sofa. Allow him to find other places where to play / sit. Normally, you should allow him access pretty much everywhere where it is not dangerous - for him, or for the other inhabitants of the house (people, pets, plants...). Nobody can be happy confined to a (doggy) bed. I am quite sure you go away from your human-bed too :)
- Train the dog to play in specific areas - but not confined to the doggy-bed. One reason why they go to different places is for temperature regulation. Since they cannot operate the thermostat (or open, close the doors or windows), they seek places where they feel comfortable.
- Try to spend as much time as possible with him, so he does not additional "boost doses" of your scent.
- Involve him in energetic activities when you have time to be with him, so when he is on hos own, he would prefer to rest, rather than chew beds and sofas :)
- Provide him with a variety of chewable toys (as a minimum, some made of soft plastic / rubber / silicone, and some of them made of textile or plush). Dogs are predators, and they will never forget their instincts. Divert his attention from the sofa to the toys. Sometimes, the cheapest toys are the most loved, so do not limit yourself to expensive brands.

With time, things will settle by themselves, usually. As the dog grows older, his habits will change too.

---

I know some of this because my parents have a dog too. We got him when he was a puppy, now he is quite old. At the beginning he was very energetic, but with time, he grew more and more wiser - and slower.

I wish you success, and happiness with your new friend.

---

PS: occasionally, the dog will destroy something. You will be lucky if he will never ever destroy anything. Ideally / luckily, he will direct his attention to the toys. Just remember: even you might occasional break a plate, a cup, or crack the phones screen when you accidentally drop it. Do not expect perfection from someone else :)